# How to setup Restricted (permission) access for Directories in Apache2 web server

Tags: permissions, apache2, settings

I am a new system admin and learning Ubuntu. 
I have to setup a restricted (permission) for directories in Apache web server. The scenario is as follows. The folders are,

```
/var/www/data/
/var/www/management/
/var/www/hrd/
/var/www/technical/
```

The users in hrd (HR Department) group must access `/var/www/hrd/` contents only.

The users in technical group must access `/var/www/technical/` contents only.

The users in management group can access all the contents.

All the users & groups can access the common `/var/www/data/` directory.

How to implement this? Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[**1. Installation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#http-installation)

The Apache2 web server is available in Ubuntu Linux. To install Apache2:
At a terminal prompt enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

[**2. Configuration**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#http-configuration) and with care about [**3. HTTPS Configuration**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration)

[**4. Sharing Write Permission**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#http-directory-permissions)

For more than one user to be able to write to the same directory it will be necessary to grant write permission to a group they share in common. The following example grants shared write permission to /var/www/html to the group "webmasters".

```
sudo chgrp -R webmasters /var/www/html
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g=rwxs "{}" \;
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod g=rw  "{}" \;
```

These commands recursively set the group permission on all files and directories in `/var/www/html` to **read write** and **set user id**. This has the effect of having the files and directories inherit their **group** and **permission** from **their parent**. Many admins find this useful for allowing multiple users to edit files in a directory tree.

If access must be granted to more than one group per directory, enable **Access Control Lists** (ACLs).

Comment: Hello swift, since I am the newbie, I referred the below URL

Comment: Hello swift, I referred the URL http://blog.secaserver.com/tag/htpasswd-group/  for Group Authentication. When I checked in Firefox I get this message : Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /secure-admin/ on this server.  Then I checked the error file : /var/log/apache2/error.log   it shows  : Permission denied: access to /secure-admin/index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/website/public_html/secure-admin/index.php') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path.   Then I changed the  permission by command chmod -R 774.  Now it gives access to all, not denying.

Comment: if you mean web users (i.e. internet users) then sure your link have methods to configure your `.htpasswd` file with needed permissions. otherwise if you need control or limiting your **OS's users or webmasters** then you should to use my solution.